# Working and feasibility of exasol "export" command

Tags: export, database-migration, data-migration, exasol, exasolution

Attempted using "export" command (https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql/export.htm) to migrate data from exasol sample table exasol_schema.ST_CATEGORIES to redshift table redshift_schema.ST_Categories:

```
SQL_EXA> Export exasol_schema.ST_CATEGORIES into jdbc driver='Redshift'
1    > at 'jdbc:redshift://redshift-instance-details.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/redshiftdb'
2    > user 'user'
3    > identified by 'password'
4    > table redshift_schema.ST_Categories;
EXA: Export exasol_schema.ST_CATEGORIES into jdbc ...

Rows affected: 8

SQL_EXA>
```

It worked like charm!

Few questions:

1. How does the exasol server 7.1.0 automatically map the columns? Becuase exasol table has column names - `CATEGORYID_B, CATEGORYNAME_B, DESCRIPTION_B`. Whereas the redshift table has column names - `CategoryID$, CategoryName$, Description$`. How did exasol map `CATEGORYID_B` to `CategoryID$`? And the similar correct mapping for other columns?
2. Can "export" command be used for enterprise use-cases (e.g. migrate TBs of data from exasol to redshift)? Is it the recommended usage of the "export" command? Or is the "export" command recommended only for small tables?
3. Does the "export" command insert data to destination database one row at a time or in batches?
4. Is it recommended to trigger several "export" command migrations in parallel? E.g. Migrate several tables (of size in GBs) in parallel using multiple "export" commands/sessions.